# Merge sort function in C

Tags: c, sorting

I have the following piece of code which represents a merge sort function

```
/* perform merge sort */
void merge_sort(int arr[], int left, int right) {
    if (left < right) {
        int middle = left + (right - left) / 2;
        merge_sort(arr, left, middle);
        merge_sort(arr, middle + 1, right);
        merge(arr, left, middle, right);
    }
}
```

What is the use of this `merge_sort(arr, middle + 1, right);`?

Comment: What do you mean by "have any scope"?

Comment: I mean if that call is necessary

Comment: The function identifier `merge_sort` is in scope within its own function body, if that is what you were asking before, but now you have changed the question to something else.

Comment: Both calls to `merge_sort` are necessary. It uses a "divide and conquer" approach to split the array into two halves, sort each half separately (hence the two calls to `merge_sort`) and then merge the two sorted halves back together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea of the [merge sort algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) is to divide the sequence to be sorted in half, sort each half, and then merge them together. This is frequently done recursively, as in this case. As a result, there must be two recursive calls, one for each half of the sequence.

If the `merge_sort(arr, middle+1, right);` call were not present, the algorithm would not be complete and the sort would not work.

As an experiment, you could try writing an example program using the merge sort function you posted. Try it with and without the line in question and see what results you get.